# Recursive functions and removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to write a dynamic button creator. So I have the `html` file

```
<body>
    <button id="0" type="button" onclick="create_button(0)">Create button 1</button>
</body>
```

and `js` file which "simulates" proper action

```
var counter = 0;

function create_button(n) {

    /*Shift up*/
    for (i=counter; i>n; i--) {
        document.getElementById(i).id = i+1;
        document.getElementById(i+1).innerHTML = i+1;
    };

    /*Create new button*/
    var new_button = document.createElement("Button");
    new_button.innerHTML = n+1;
    new_button.type = "button";
    new_button.id = n+1;
    function helper() {
        create_button(n+1);
    };
    new_button.addEventListener('click', helper );

    document.body.insertBefore(new_button,document.getElementById(n).nextSibling);

    counter++;
};
```

However `/*Shift up*/` part only changes `id` and `innerHTML` of buttons not the action of `click`. So in order to fix that I need to add in `/*Shift up*/` two lines which should work as

```
document.getElementById(i+1).addEventListener('click', helper(i+1) );
document.getElementById(i+1).removeEventListener('click', helper(i) );
```

Clearly It will not work. Due to recursive nature of `create_button` function, I imagine that `helper` should be moved outside of `create_button`. But I have no idea how to do it.

**Some additional info** I simplified the code, but in practice buttons have some addition functions which depend on n. Let say that we also want to alert the position of the button. So we change helper to

```
function helper() {
    create_button(n+1);
    alert(n+1);
};
```

See in https://jsfiddle.net/o3Lsttyq/3/ what alerts say. Click for example 1,1,3.

Comment: Are you trying to get the buttons to show in backwards order? (e.g. 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: Here is your example in a fiddle with eventListener attached later.  What's not right about it?  https://jsfiddle.net/o3Lsttyq/

Comment: @helllomatt No. 1,2,3... Having counter buttons. I press n button. Everething from n+1..counter is shifted to n+2..counter+1 and I create new_button n+1. Is it anything wrong with my code?

Comment: @jmargolisvt Maybe my question was oversimplified. Can you see the problem now?

Comment: IDs cannot start with numbers.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos js treat them as text. I can change n to n.toString(), but it is redundant.

Comment: This might work for now, but the specs say it shouldn't. Normally you add a prefix, like `el_0`

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I will keep that in mind when I'll go back to my actual code. Thx. How about the question above. Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're adjusting `id` so that it always matches the current index and your function `helper` wants that same index, it seems all you need to do is move your `helper` function out and change it to something like:

```
function helper(){
  var n1 = this.id; // effectively "n+1"
  alert(n1);
}
```

You don't need to call `create_button` with that argument either since the data you want can be pulled out of `this`.

(Also, you shouldn't be using the `id` attribute for that kind of thing. You should instead be using `data-` prefixed attributes as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). As well, refactoring around using `this` instead of using `getElementById()` means you could drop the need for tracking the element's index.)

Refactoring for fun:

```html
<body>
    <button type="button">Create button 1</button>
</body>
```

```js
function create_button(){
  var index = (this.innerHTML|0) + 1;
  var new_button = document.createElement("button");
  new_button.type = "button";
  new_button.addEventListener('click',create_button);
  document.body.insertBefore(new_button,this.nextSibling);

  var target = new_button;
  while(target) {
    target.innerHtml = index;
    target = target.nextSibling;
    index += 1;
  }
}
document.body.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener('click',create_button);
```

Comment: It works perfectly. This problem really bothered me for a while. `this` is what I wanted. Thx

Comment: Great! I will refactor mine as well. i feel that my code is too complex.

Comment: What `|0` does in `(this.innerHTML|0)`? Is it set `0` if `this.innerHTML` is undefined?

Comment: `|` is binary `or` operator (different from `||`, the logical `or` operator). Using it with `0` essentially coerces the other argument to `Number`. Non-number text (like "test", for example) end up as `0` rather than `NaN`.